# Https does not work at my AWS's Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I set up load balancer at my instances.

If load balancer is set with https (443) only at listeners and inbound of its security group. I can't load page using https://domain name.com.

If I added http(80) to both listeners and its security group. It works with http://domain name.com.

Where could be the problem? Is it at my source codes or what could be wrong?

EDIT

Load balancer's listeners are as follow currently.
[image]

Comment: Do you set the internal Port to 80? Your SSL Certificate is correct?

Comment: @Stony I have updated at EDIT.  Yes internal port is 80 and have SSL certificate.

Comment: Ok that looks correct. Are you sure that you've set the correct DNS Cname to your Domain and that it resolves correctly?

Comment: I don't use Cname. I use IPV4 address with Alias and Alias tag was chosen to the load balancer. So that my domain name is attached to the load balancer.

Comment: Since my domain name is attached to the load balancer correctly and I can use http with domain name to load my page, load balancer is ok. But why https with domain.com does not work?

Comment: You have to set the domain name of your Loadbalancer as CNAME of your domain of you use the IP you don't use the loadbalancer...

Comment: here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html) it is explained as they are same.

Comment: I think your go directly to your machine ant don't use the loadbalancer otherwise it would work ;) i can't say anymore.

Comment: I think my code has some problem to load with https. Is it possible? or the page able to load with http is that should be able to load with https also?

Comment: Normally that should work... use a test.php and try to call them then it's not your application...

Comment: Thanks. My code has problem. I load an html page with https and http located in the same folder. Both work. Yeah now I know where to solve.